# Chef Run Virtualenv Bash

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

In **Chef-solo** I can't figure out how to **run a command from a users bash**.

In Chef-Solo on Vagrant, I provision and install **virtualenv**, it works if I login and type `$ virtualenv` or `$ virtualenvwrapper`.

I can't run it from Chef-Solo get these to work:

I tried this, but it doesn't do anything (no errors i can see):

```
execute 'mkvirtualenv' do
    user node.default["username"]
    group node.default["username"]
    command "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh | bash && mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute /home/#{node.default["username"]}/projects/#{node.default["params"]["vhost"]} | bash"
end
```

I tried this but it has errors:

```
bash 'mkvirtualenv' do
    cwd "/home/#{node.default['username']}/projects/"
    user node.default["username"]
    environment ({
        'HOME' => '/home/#{node.default["username"]}'
    })
    code "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute #{node.default["params"]["vhost"]}"
end
```

**Update**

I have also tried this:

```
bash 'mkvirtualenv' do
    cwd "/home/#{node.default["username"]}/projects/"
    user node.default["username"]
    environment ({
        'HOME' => ::Dir.home(node.default['username']),
        'USER' => node.default['username']
    })
    code <<-EOH
        source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh \
        mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute #{node.default["params"]["vhost"]}
    EOH
end
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Just wondering why you have `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh | bash` in the execute resource? When you run `bash` it's spinning up a new shell and that's probably why you're not seeing anything. Try executing the same command you have in the `bash` block.

Comment: Because I need bash to execute, sh won't work. I added another attempt with bash above. :)

Comment: What happens with the updated bash resource?

Comment: ==> default: [2015-02-19T16:10:21+00:00] INFO: execute[virtualenvwrapper] ran successfully  -- but it doesnt do anything

Comment: ==> default: [2015-02-19T16:10:22+00:00] INFO: bash[mkvirtualenv] ran successfully.
The username is `vagrant` but when I login and try `workon projectname` I get: `ERROR: Environment 'indieflix' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv projectname.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [chef-solo passing custom json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614157/chef-solo-passing-custom-json)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is another topic :)

Comment: @JREAM the root cause of your problem is the same (the use of `node.default`), I've already answered it in the other question, this one is clearly a duplicate at this time. If you really encounter a problem with bash resource with clean code, update (edit) the question or open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second update is nearly there.  The problem is the trailing `\` on the `source` line - this is a continuation line, so it's as though you have written the subsequent `mkvirtualenv` on the same line, giving you a command like:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute #{node.default["params"]["vhost"]}
```

I believe that `source` passes `mkvirtualenv` and the rest as arguments to your `virtualenvwrapper` script - but I don't think it is what you intended judging by your earlier attempt.  Try removing that backslash and see what happens.