# chef-solo passing custom json

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am desperately trying to figure out how to apply a few **node variables** in Chef-Solo. Otherwise I have to keep reprovisioning.

**Step 1**, I log into the provisioned box:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo chef-solo -o virtualenv::addsite -j /vagrant/resources/attr_test.json
```

**Step 2**, I have a JSON file passing data that im trying to run against in a recipe. *I believe this has node.normal mode which is higher priority than default?*

Here is what i have at the moment in
**attr_test.json**

```
{
    "username": "vagrant",
    "params": {
        "vhost": "fake"
    },
    "user": {
        "name": "vagrant"
    },
    "overwrite_attributes": {
        "username": "vagrant"
    }
}
```

This is the recipe but I can't get the node.default data to populate.

**virtualenv/recipes/addsite.rb**

```
bash 'mkvirtualenv' do
    cwd "/home/#{node.default['username']}/projects/"
    user node.default['username']
    environment ({
        'HOME' => ::Dir.home(node.default['username']),
        'USER' => node.default['username']
    })
    code <<-EOH
        source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh \
        mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute #{node.default['params']['vhost']}
    EOH
end
```

**The Error**

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
Option user must be a kind of [String, Integer]!  You passed {}.


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cookbooks/virtualenv/recipes/addsite.rb:8:in `block in from_file'
  /var/chef/cookbooks/virtualenv/recipes/addsite.rb:6:in `from_file'
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Do I need to pass in a **Chef::Environment** or **Chef::Role** in the JSON for **json_type**?

**UPDATE**

Here is another thing I've tried with Chef::Node, Chef::Environment, Chef::Role, etc. I still get "You Passed {}" and can't see the username or the other items :(

```
{
   "json_class": "Chef::Node",
   "chef_type": "node",
   "name": "node_test",
   "normal": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
    "normal_attributes": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
   "override_attributes": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
    "override": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
   "default": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
    "default_attributes": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
   "automatic": {},
   "run_list": [
   ]
}
```

**Solution**

I ticked off the right answer. Here is my JSON so it helps anyone! The problem was the RECIPE:

> {
>       "json_class": "Chef::Node",
>       "chef_type": "node",
>       "name": "node_test",
>       "normal": {
>           "username": "vagrant",
>           "params": {
>               "vhost": "fakeit"
>           }
>       },
>       "override": {},
>       "default": {},
>       "automatic": {},
>       "run_list": [] }

- To WRITE/SET a value I just use `node.default["value"]`
- To READ a value I just use `node["value"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `node.default['whatever']` only when you set the default value for an attribute in a recipe.

To use an atrtibute just use `node['whatever']`

I think the error comes from the 'USER' environement variable getting an empty value.

This code should work as expected with your first json file.

```
bash 'mkvirtualenv' do
    cwd "/home/#{node['username']}/projects/"
    user node['username']
    environment ({
        'HOME' => ::Dir.home(node['username']),
        'USER' => node['username']
    })
    code <<-EOH
        source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh \
        mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute node['params']['vhost']
    EOH
end
```

I see no need for `#{}` around `node['params']['vhost']` as it is not in a string needing interpolation but I may be wrong with HereDoc syntax if it fails, readd it.

Comment: I will try this. I am using the gem "foodcritic" to validate code and it says you should use default (which doesnt make a lot of sense to me) so ill try this way.

Comment: Oh and reviewed the doc for -j any attribute in this file is treated as normal level, that explain why you get nothing calling node.default

Comment: Yup you are right, Thank you so much. This has driven me CRAZY. So to SET a value `node.default['something'] = 1`, and to GET a value `node['something']` -- This way the json WORKS! With something like: `{
    "json_class": "Chef::Node",
    "chef_type": "node",
    "name": "node_test",
    "normal": {
        "username": "vagrant",
        "params": {
            "vhost": "fakeit"
        }
    },
}`

Comment: @Tensibal I cant recall I have messed around so much with this, but I know `node[:username]` was one it said not to use.

Comment: Yes, symbol an method access are discouraged,  use strings, in single quotes if there's no need to interpolation (no variables) and double quotes if you need interpolation (it's a guideline, nothing mandatory)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have set "node['params']['vhost']" attribute?

If that's not issue, try to set "default_attributes" instead of "overwrite_attributes", because there is no attributes to override.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have those params getting set in a recipe `node.default['params']['template'] = "django.erb"` which works great. But I can't even get the username to load which is set `node.default["username"] = "vagrant"`  -- Ill update my JSON to show what I try again

Comment: This has nothing to do. Default, normal and overrides are level of precedence, there's no need to have one at a lower level to define an attribute at override level.

Comment: tnx @Tensibai it's good to know, at the end it's strange to override something thats not set yet

Comment: @rastasheep In fact  default/normal and override are level of precedence. As in ruby accessing an unknow variable set it to nil at the access, you're still overriding something. [More details here](http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) on how it is managed in a chef run